# android, seekbar drawable, what id/background, id/secondaryProgress and id/progress stand for?

Tags: android, seekbar

I'm trying to make custom `seekbar` background. In examples I can find it is done via layer list with 3 layers. Layers' ids are:

`@android:id/background

@android:id/secondaryProgress

@android:id/progress`

What each item actually does?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`secondaryProgress` is an optional, additional progress in the bar. It is mostly used to display a buffering progress like you know it from streaming videos.

`progress` and `background` should actually be self-explanatory. `progress` is the main progress, the loaded part, and `background` is the background of the `SeekBar`, the part that still needs to get loaded.